# Numbering publication list in Hugo Academic

Tags: r, markdown, hugo

I am setting up a website using [Hugo with the Academic template](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/tree/master/exampleSite). I would like to number my list of publications in the reverse order. Something like this:

```
3. Smith, J. (2018).....
2. Smith, J. (2017).....
1. Smith, J. (2015).....
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I couldn't find any [detailed info on this](https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/981)